# Adjust height of parent div depends on the child divs

Tags: html, sass

I want my parent height to be auto when it has 1 or 2 child divs and if it has more than 3 div will have a specific height. How to do it? Is it possible?

```
<div class="parent-div"> 
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.parent-div {
  height: 370px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;

  &:nth-child(n+1) ~ div {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: set max height.

Answer (score 0):

In the Page Loaded context, use JavaScript to find the div and count its contents.  Then apply CSS as appropriate.

Setting max height would always constrain the height, even when only one or two divs were present.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to style the parent of an element using purely CSS.

If you know the amount of items during rendering the HTML or have a way to modify the class when the DOM changes, you could create some modifier classes and use them alongside your base class.

```
.parent-div {
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.parent-div-few {
  /*
   * Not even needed, auto is the initial value.
   */
  height: auto;
}

.parent-div-lot {
  /*
   * Not even needed, auto is the initial value.
   */
  height: 370px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And use a different HTML structure for the two different cases:

```
<div class="parent-div parent-div-few">
  <div class="child">
  <div class="child">
<div>

<div class="parent-div parent-div-lot">
  <div class="child">
  <div class="child">
  <div class="child">
<div>
```